# Getting users from UserManager using HotChocolate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, hotchocolate

**How to get list of users from `UserManager` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` using `[ScopedService]`**

Below is what I already tried:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using hostapp.Data;
using hostapp.Models;
using HotChocolate;
using HotChocolate.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace hostapp.GraphQL
{
    public class Query
    {
        // 1.
        [UseDbContext(typeof(DataContext))]
        public IQueryable<AppUser> Users([ScopedService] UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            return (IQueryable<AppUser>)userManager.Users;
        }
        
        // 2.
        [UseDbContext(typeof(DataContext))]
        public async Task<List<AppUser>> Users([ScopedService] UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            return await userManager.Users.ToListAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

Input:

```
query {
  users {
    emailConfirmed
  }
}
```

Output:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "users"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "users": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `[ScopedService]` but rather `[Service]`
You really only even need to use `[ScopedService]` in case of a `DBContext` in combination with `UseDbContext`.
We will fix this confusion in the next version